# What are before_create, validates_presence_of, has_many etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand what these statements *do*, but not how to refer to them. They exist within a class, outside of that class's methods and perform a variety of functions.

Collectively, what are they called?

Comment: They are method calls.

Comment: They can be a bit magical-seeming at first glance, partly because of Ruby's optional brackets, which tend to be omitted.  For example, this `has_many :foos, :through => :bars` is shorthand for `has_many(:foos, {:through => :bars})`.  When you see it with the brackets added, it's easier to see that `has_many` is a method name, `:foos` is the primary argument, and `:through => :bars` is an optional key-value pair passed through in a hash, where the hash is effectively the second argument to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These methods are really just class methods. Try this:

```
class Test
  def self.before_create
    puts "before_create"
  end

  before_create
end
```

The specific use case you mentioned - Rails DSL methods such as `before_create`, that are only available inside a `class` body — are often called **class macros**. Rubys metaprogramming abilities give you multiple ways to build them. A simple one is to make them private:

```
module Foo
  private

  def before_create
    puts "before_create"
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo

  before_create
end
```

`before_create` is now accessible inside the class body, but not from outside:

```
Bar.before_create
NoMethodError: private method `before_create' called for Bar:Class
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure Ruby terms, they are all just method calls.

However, they do have a common theme. In the way they are constructed and used, you could consider them part of a [Domain-Specific Language (DSL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)  - the ones you list are part of Active Record's DSL for creating data models.

Ruby lends itself well to creating DSL-like mini languages, using mix-ins or a base class in order to provide a set of class methods, which in turn will store data or create methods on the class and instances of it using meta-programming techniques.